# How to drag a value after comparing TWO tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have table A & Table B.

I would like to compare one of the column A (Table A) to column A (Table B).

If the values from column A (Table A) matche column A (Table B), I would like to drag column B(Table B) values onto a created table on php page.

Is there a way to do this? your support and help is thoroughly appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: By Drag you mean copy? I'm not sure your intention is clear.

Comment: So on the page itself, I would like to list Table A on to a created table on the page. However I would also like to list column_B value from Table B onto the created table if Column A (Table A) matches Colum A(Table B)

Comment: Yes Copy. I apologize for the confusion

Comment: So, isn't this just a simple query? I still don't have an exact idea of where your problem is. For what it seems, you need to modify your query to include the comparison and resulting column. That way you have from the beginning the data as needed for your php page.

Answer (score 1):

This is called a `SELECT` query. It's how you get data out of your database. It's how phpmyadmin, or whatever you are using, gets the data in the table so it can present it to you. To get everything from `TableA` it submits:

```
SELECT * FROM TableA;
```

What you want to do is done using a `JOIN` in the `SELECT` query in the `FROM` clause:

```
SELECT Tablea.ColumnA, Tableb.ColumnB
FROM
    TableA
    INNER JOIN TableB ON
        TableA.ColumnA = TableB.ColumnA;
```

Submit this sql and you will have `ColumnA` from `TableA` and `ColumnB` from `TableB` where `ColumnA` in `TableA` is equal to `ColumnA` from `TableB`

There is no "dragging" or "Copying" happening here. The results you are viewing are ephemeral and will not persist in a new table, unless you write the SQL to make that happen. If you wanted to store the results from that query in a new table (TableC) then:

```
CREATE TableC AS
    SELECT Tablea.ColumnA, Tableb.ColumnB
    FROM
        TableA
        INNER JOIN TableB ON
            TableA.ColumnA = TableB.ColumnA;
```